# Installing matlab for python

Tags: python, matlab, cmd, matlab-engine

I'm trying to install matlab engine for python but doesn't work, I'm doing that from command line and doesn't display anything. These are my steps:
I have add python tho my environment path
than I found matlabroot and I get in with cd in command line
I have installed matlab kernel
than I run the code python setup.py install --prefix='C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'

But doesn't work, and I have no message or error.
What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I know.
First, find matlabroot on matlab : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a
Than, go to conda prompt
and get in the matlab directory : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\extern\engines\python
then type on conda prompt : python setup.py install

Make sure you have python add to the env path

Answer (score 0):

`python setup.py install` is what mathworks suggests.

[Mathworks document here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)

Run `python -V` to check if you are running the version you want to use.